# Have CMake rebuild custom targets when transitive dependency outdated

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I have a multi-directory CMake project where I generate two files `b` and `c`. Then I have an executable `d_target` that needs `c`.

- File `b` depends on some configuration file `a`
- File `c` depends on file `b`
- Executable target `d_target` needs `c`, it's a **generated header file**.

I added two [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) calls to generate the files and added dependencies.
Then, I added two [`add_custom_target()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) calls to make the targets available throughout the multi-directory project.

```
file a > file b > b_target > file c > c_target > d_target
```

The first time that I build `c_target`, all dependencies are built and the file `c` is equal to `b` and `b` equal to `a`.

Now, when I change the 'configuration' `a` and build `d_target`, `d_target` is not rebuilt.

How can I have CMake rebuild targets when any of their dependencies change?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(abcd)

# ./b/CMakeLists.txt
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b
  COMMAND cat ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a > ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a)
add_custom_target(b_target DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b)

# ./c/CMakeLists.txt
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c
  COMMAND cat ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b > ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c
  DEPENDS b_target ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b)
add_custom_target(c_target DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c)

# ./d/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(d_target ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/d.cpp)
add_dependencies(d_target c_target) 
# will not generate:
# add_dependencies(d_target c_target  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c)
```

**In my specific situation, the commands for `b` and `c` and `d` are in CMakeLists.txt in their respective subdirectories.**

Demonstration:

```
$ make d_target
[ 20%] Generating b
[ 20%] Built target b_target
[ 40%] Generating c
[ 60%] Built target c_target
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/d_target.dir/d.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable d_target
[100%] Built target d_target
$ touch ../a
$ make d_target
[ 20%] Generating b
[ 20%] Built target b_target
[ 40%] Generating c
[ 60%] Built target c_target
[100%] Built target d_target
```

When I try to add the `c` file to `add_dependencies(d_target ...)`, CMake fails:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "/home/tom/tmp/abcd/build/c" of target
  "d_target" does not exist.
```

Comment: As currently written in the code, `add_custom_command` in the `b/CMakeLists.txt` will create `b` in the build directory for `b`. But `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b` in the `c/CMakeLists.txt` refers to the `b` in the build directory for `c`. So you have different `b` files in different directories.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your comment, I clarified the example a little but this is not the underlying problem.

Comment: Oh, you need to add `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b` as DEPENDS of `add_custom_command` in `c/CMakeLists.txt`. Otherwise CMake (and Make) doesn't know that you want to rebuild the file `c` if the file `b` has been changed. Specifying a target as dependency automatically adds file-level dependency only if the target is an executable or a library (created with `add_executable` or `add_library` calls). Since your `b_target` is a custom target, it doesn't add file-level dependency. See also documentation for [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html).

Comment: @fabian my fault, I meant `make c_target`

Comment: Depend on the file, not on the target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev this seems to fix the problem for the add_custom_command case. 
Now in the end I have an executable target `d` that relies on the generated file `c` where it fails. I update the question.

Comment: @KamilCuk in the end I need `c` for an executable target and I cannot seem to depend on the file `c` with the `add_dependencies(d_target ...)` syntax (CMake error).

Comment: `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c` is a **file**, not a **target**. So it cannot be used in `add_dependencies` command which expects targets. (In CMake a *file* and a *target* are not interchangeable things).

Comment: "Executable target d_target needs c." - Executable target `d_target` is created from a single source file, `d.cpp`. **Why** file `c` is needed for compiling/linking `d_target`? **How** file `c` affects on the compilation or linking of `d_target`?

Comment: Good point, it's through a generated header file! It's actually a piece of firmware generated with an independent toolchain (TI SDDF) that should be embedded in the target for flashing at runtime.

Comment: Since CMake automatically detects dependencies from a header file, included via `#include` directive in the source file, I assume that you want to express dependency from the header file added via `-include` option in the compiler command line. Am I right? I almost sure that SO already has questions on this topic (in CMake express dependency from the file added via `-include` option) ...

Comment: The file is generated in a directory that is added to the `target_include_directories()`. I'm not sure how CMake would be able to detect such a dependency. 
The compiler command line option would be `-I/path/to/generated/directory` which would contain the generated header.

Comment: CMake either scans source files for `#include` directive or lets a compiler to generate a header dependencies (e.g `gcc` with `-M` option). Are you sure that `d.cpp` **actually** includes your special header file, directly or indirectly? And please, update the question post to reflect your problem (dependency from a header file, included from the source file).

Comment: Actually, you may try to add your header file directly into `add_executable` call: `add_executable(d_target ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/d.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c)`. By looking into extension of the file, CMake will determine that the file needn't to be compiled, but adds a dependency from that file. However, it is preferred to understand why automatic detection of header dependencies is not work in your case.

Comment: (unrelated to the problem) It smells like you include `b/CMakeLists.txt` and other `CMakeLists.txt` via `include` command (so a variable like `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` isn't changed when CMake goes from the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` to the `CMakeLists.txt` in inner directories. This is a **misusing**: files `CMakeLists.txt` are intended to be included with `add_subdirectory` command only.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestions out tomorrow! (CET tz)

Comment: I'm adding the CMakeLists.txt through `add_subdirectory()`. 
When adding the file as a dependency of the target, the target is also not rebuilt. I will try to reformulate the question and provide a minimal example to reproduce the problem. Thanks a thousandfold for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution with explanatory comments in the `c/CMakeLists.txt` snippet.
You can change the value to `SOME_DEFINE` inside of `b/a` and re-build to see it update.

root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(abcd)

add_subdirectory(b)
add_subdirectory(c)
add_subdirectory(d)
```

b/a

```
#define SOME_DEFINE 4
```

b/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(B_INPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a")
set(B_OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${B_OUTPUT}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${B_INPUT} ${B_OUTPUT}
    DEPENDS ${B_INPUT}
    )

add_custom_target(b_target DEPENDS ${B_OUTPUT})
```

c/CMakeLists.txt

```
get_target_property(B_OUTPUT_DIR b_target BINARY_DIR)
set(C_INPUT "${B_OUTPUT_DIR}/b")
set(C_OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${C_OUTPUT}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${C_INPUT} ${C_OUTPUT}
    DEPENDS ${C_INPUT}
    )

# Using "_c_target" as a local target and intending the non underscore prefix
# for use outside this CMakeLists.txt file
add_custom_target(_c_target DEPENDS ${C_OUTPUT})

# This forces `b_target` to be built prior to `_c_target`.  Since the custom
# command to build `C_INPUT` is in a different CMakeLists, CMake doesn't
# understand that `C_INPUT` is created by a custom command and thus doesn't know
# to generate it.
# This is only needed because the custom command for `C_INPUT` is in another
# file.  If the custom command was here, in this file, CMake would implicitly
# hook up the dependency for us through the custom commands and we wouldn't need
# `b_target`.
add_dependencies(_c_target b_target)

# Since `C_OUTPUT` is a header file, we create a header only library that the
# executable can link to.  This header only library provides the include
# directory of the generated file.
add_library(c_target INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(c_target INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

# Per docs for add_dependencies
#
#   Dependencies added to an imported target or an interface library are
#   followed transitively"
# 
# This ensures that the `_c_target` will be built prior to anything that may end
# up using `c_target`.
add_dependencies(c_target _c_target)
```

d/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(d_target ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/d.cpp)
target_link_libraries(d_target PRIVATE c_target)
```

d/d.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "c"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("The value is %d.\n", SOME_DEFINE);
}
```